# How to make "Blog pages show at most" setting not affect custom queries

Tags: wp-query

I want my blog page to display 5 posts at most. But I have many custom queries (wp_query) on my site, some of them embedded together: how to make `Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most` setting NOT affect my custom queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating your own custom `WP_Query` queries, you can use the `posts_per_page` parameter:

```
$args = array( 
    // ...
    'posts_per_page' => $some_number,
    //...
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you want *all* the posts, use `-1` as your `$some_number`.

#### Reference

- [WP_Query » Pagination Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Answer (score 3):

The preferred method would be to hook the `pre_get_posts()` action.

```
function set_home_pagesize( $query )
{
    if ( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_home() )
    {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        return;
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_home_pagesize', 1 );
```

This is assuming that your blog page is your home. You may need to use different conditionals if it is not.